# jQuery remove or add style to last of specific type of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, element

I have a jQuery page that has a few things going on. All of the functionalities are complete. The only thing that's not complete is removing the last hr (only the last one) of each table. I need to know how to the last of a specific type of element in an array. All the elements that are wrapped in the tables are their own array. I need to loop through each of those tables and only remove the last hr in the table for each table. I've tried many methods and can't seem to get it. The code I have below only removes the last hr for the last table. This doesn't complete my task.

jQuery/ JavaScript Code (Everything works except for removing the last HR)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var H2SingerTitles = $("h2.toggleSinger");
  for (i = 2; i < H2SingerTitles.length; i++) {
    var currentH2Singer = H2SingerTitles[i];
    var siblingsofH2Singer = 
    $(currentH2Singer).nextUntil("h2.toggleSinger");
    $(siblingsofH2Singer).wrapAll("<table></table>");
    for (j = 0; j < siblingsofH2Singer.length; j++) {
      $("hr").last().css("border-top", "none");
    } // line ends for loop with j counter
  } // line ends for loop with i counter 
  togglerHeaders.slice(0,2).removeClass("toggleSinger");
  $(".toggleSinger").next().hide();
  $(".toggleSinger").click(function(){
    $(".toggleSinger").next().toggleClass();
  });
}); 
</script>
```

The inner loop (which is below) is what I'm trying to use to loop through the tables one by one then remove only the last HR in the table. For some reason it's not working.

```
for (j = 0; j < siblingsofH2Singer.length; j++) {
  $("hr").last().css("border-top", "none");
} // line ends for loop with j counter
```

Below is my HTML

```
<div id="mainPage">
  <h2 class=""><span class="title">Whitney Houston</span></h2>
  <div class="aboutInfo">
    <img src="whitney_houston.jpg" height="150">
    <a href="www.whitneyhouston.com" target="_blank"><h3><em>The Voice</em> 
    </h3></a>
    <h3>Worldwide Famous Vocalist, Singer and Performer</h3> 
    <p>I will always love you</p>
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div> 

  <h2 class=""><span class="title">Mariah Carey</span></h2>
  <div class="aboutInfo">
    <img src="mariah_carey.jpg" height="150">
    <a href="www.mariahcarey.com" target="_blank"><h3><em>Whistle 
    Register</em></h3></a>
    <h3>Worldwide Famous Vocalist, Singer and Performer</h3> 
    <p>Hero</p>
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <h2 class="toggleSinger"><span class="title">Michael Jackson</span></h2>
  <table style="display: none;">
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <img src="michael_jackson.jpg" height="150">
      <a href="www.michaeljackson.com" target="_blank"><h3><em>King of
      Pop</em></h3></a>
      <h3>Worldwide Superstar Singer, Dancer and Performer</h3> 
      <p>Billie Jean</p>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <img src="jackson_5.jpg" height="150">
      <a href="www.jackson5.com" target="_blank"><h3><em>The Jackson 5</em> 
      </h3></a>
      <h3>Worldwide Famous R and B Group</h3> 
      <p>ABC</p>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </table>

  <h2 class="toggleSinger"><span class="title">Diana Ross</span></h2>
  <table style="display: none;">
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <img src="diana_ross.jpg" height="150">
      <a href="www.dianaross.com" target="_blank"><h3><em>The Original 
      Diva</em></h3></a>
      <h3>Worldwide Superstar Singer</h3> 
      <p>I'm coming out</p>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <img src="diana_ross.jpg" height="150">
      <a href="www.dianaross.com" target="_blank"><h3><em>The Supremes</em> 
      </h3></a>
      <h3>Worldwide Famous Girl Group</h3> 
      <p>Stop in the name of love</p>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </table>

  <h2 class="toggleSinger"><span class="title">Lionel Richie</span></h2>
  <table style="display: none;">
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <img src="lionel_richie.jpg" height="150">
      <a href="www.lionelrichie.com" target="_blank"><h3><em></em></h3></a>
      <h3>Worldwide Superstar Singer and Pianist</h3> 
      <p>All night long</p>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <img src="diana_ross.jpg" height="150">
      <a href="www.dianaross.com" target="_blank"><h3><em>The Commodores</em> 
      </h3></a>
      <h3>Worldwide Famous Group and Band</h3> 
      <p>Brickhouse</p>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </table>

  <h2 class="toggleSinger"><span class="title">Smokey Robinson</span></h2>
  <table style="display: none;">
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <img src="smokey_robinson.jpg" height="150">
      <a href="www.smokeyrobinson.com" target="_blank"><h3><em></em></h3></a>
      <h3>Worldwide Singer and Songwriter</h3> 
      <p>Cruising</p>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutInfo">
      <img src="the_miracles.jpg" height="150">
      <a href="www.themiracles.com" target="_blank"><h3><em>The Miracles</em> 
      </h3></a>
      <h3>Worldwide Famous R and B Group</h3> 
      <p>Ooh Baby Baby</p>
      <br>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('hr:last-child').remove();` or, with CSS: `hr:last-child { display: none; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to remove the last HR on each table you don't need the for loop, try this.

```
$("table").each(function(){ $(this).find("hr").last().remove(); });
```

Comment: Thanks but when I put in this code it messes up a few other elements on the page and it causes some of the images to shift.

Comment: Can you give a link to a live page? The code provided does remove the last HR in each table, so maybe your requirements are a little different?

Comment: It's fine I was able to make it work. Thank you very much.